# PHP Prepared statements issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm getting error message

```
Column 'fname' cannot be null
```

In fact it is not null. I think that there is something wrong with binding. Do I need to bind NOW() too?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`fname`, `mname`, `lname`, `email`, `pass`, `reg_dt`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())") or die(htmlspecialchars($db->error));

$rc = $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $fname, $mname, $lname, $email, $pass) or die(htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
```

??

Comment: you can use not null in table, and timestamp. Also, You don't need to bind NOW();

Comment: I don't wnat to update time stamp on row update

Comment: Can you provide the content of the variables you bind?

Comment: +1 to @Marcus, more specifically, are you sure `$fname` is a PHP variable with a non-`null` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema probably has a `NOT NULL` attribute for fname, which is why you are getting the null error.

According to your code you appear to be binding the params correctly, did you test to see if $fname actually as a value?

An alternate construct, for the sake of clarity (personally I don't like the ?, ?, ? binding). Also, let me qualify the following code by saying that it's PDO, not mysqli, the OP didn't indicate which was being used, that that it is just for demonstrative purposes only:

```
$sql = 
    "INSERT INTO `users` " .
    "SET fname = :fname, " .
    "mname = :mname, " .
    "lname = :lname, " .
    "email = :email, " .
    "pass = :pass, " .
    "reg_dt = NOW()";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindValue(':fname', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STRING);
$stmt->bindValue(':mname', $mname, PDO::PARAM_STRING);
$stmt->bindValue(':lname', $lname, PDO::PARAM_STRING);
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STRING);
$stmt->bindValue(':pass', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STRING);
```

Or if you don't prefer the construct, you may consider adding a `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute to your timestamp column:

```
`reg_dt` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Looked like PDO to me. Sytax wasn't 'totally' wrong, just forgot to remove the SET from the subsequent rows when I copied / pasted them.

Comment: @Phil: See http://us3.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php. What specifically is wrong with the `INSERT` syntax? Your link to MySQL docs, example #2 backed up that I can do a `SET` then comma delimited list of cols and values. Not to mention I just ran the same query from command line to make sure.

Comment: My sincere apologies. Wasn't aware of MySQL's bastardisation of the `INSERT` syntax. If you're going to push PDO (which gets a +1 from me), you may need to explain that it's different to the mysqli lib currently in use by the OP